# Debugging form validation in Pycharm

Tags: django, django-forms, pycharm

I am trying to debug form validation in Django with Pycharm. Validation of my form fails at an image I upload via an ImageField and I want to find out why it's failing on it. However, whenever I try to debug the validation process and step into and through the form initialization with the POST data, it doesn't even try validating and at the end throws an error because of empty fields when trying to save the form data to the database. It is driving me nuts... how can the behavior change depending on whether I observe the individual steps or not?
I also tried to set several break points, e.g. during the full-clean method of the BaseForm class, but it doesn't seem to ever get there.

**Edit:** Here is some code

My model & form:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    ...
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='car_images/',blank=True,null=True)

class CarForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Car
```

My View:

```
def create_car(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        car_form = CarForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if car_form.is_valid():
            ...
```

Comment: Without your code noone will be able to help you.

Comment: Does your form have `enctype="multipart/form-data"`?

Comment: Yes, also everything works fine when I replace the ImageField by a FileField. Something is wrong with the validation (PIL is installed, verifying the image file with PIL manually in the code works fine, I am on Windows), I assume. However, the question is more about the debugging problem.

Comment: Hi, I've created an [issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-7373). Could you please attach a sample project to it, for me to be able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: Looks like PyCharm calling "error" form property while trying to show form in "Variables" frame in "Debug" tool window. On `BaseForm.__init__` `self._errors` is never None but ErrorDict, so validation is never performed.
You can set breakpoint on `self._errors = None`, add this variable to "Wathces" and hit F8. It's very funny.

Comment: @muffinmad It's not funny at all. This is a pain! :) I'm confronted with this twise. Have you found some workaround?

Comment: @raacer Yeap! I'm using vim again :) With jedi and couple other plugins. Unfortunately, PyCharm has some other little issues that distracts me from writing code.

Answer (score 8):

This is a real pain. I've got this problem twice, and still have not found good solution.

**This is an example of safe debugging when you override the form's `__init__` method.**

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Disable form validation for debugging purposes unless the
        # object is fully initialized. Set breakpoints BELOW this line.
        del self._errors

        # Write some additional initializations here, debug safely.
        ...

        # Initialization is finished. Enable form validation.
        self._errors = None
```

If you want to debug the base form classes then patch Django code in the same way.

You can either leave or remove this additional code after debugging - this does not make significant difference. But it's better to leave for the case you need this in the future.

**So, what is really going on here?**

(bugreport on Django project site: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24710)

It seems the problem is that Django's `BaseForm.errors` property getter (which is really a method with `@property` decorator) does too much. It calls the `full_clean()` method which changes the `_errors` property value so that `errors` getter does not do same work again on repeating calls.

```
class BaseForm(object):

    @property
    def errors(self):
        if self._errors is None:
            self.full_clean()
        return self._errors

    def full_clean(self):
        self._errors = ErrorDict()
        ...
```

Of course PyCharm debugger assumes that properties are just properties, and they do not do critical changes to the internal state of the objects. So the debugger calls the `errors` getter to show it's value in the "Variables" window when you debug the `__ini__` method. And this breaks the normal execution flow.

(This is why you should define methods like `get_error()` in such cases, not properties)

One possible suggestion may be to avoid breakpoints and step-by-step execution inside of the form's `__init__` method. But if you really need to debug it then modify the code so that the `_errors` property does not exist during the step-by-step execution. This will prevent calls to the `full_clean` method. PyCharm debugger will receive error each time it will try to access the `errors` property.

**Note**: the `errors` property may be evaluated on any step when execution is paused, even outside of the `__init__` method. This probably will not affect the result if all fields are fully initialized already (remember to do this in the `__init__` method only). However you may find that you still can not debug the form validation process because the form appears validated before you reach the `is_valid` method call. In this case set a breakpoint inside of the `full_clean` method, and don't stop between the form instantiation point and this breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is also reported to JetBrains PyCharm as issue number PY-39729.