# django is_valid only fails when no breakpoint

Tags: django, django-forms, inline-formset

Good day,

We have a formset based on the `inlineformset_factory`. In the view function that processes the POST, the `is_valid` function only succeeds if we are in debug with a breakpoint set on the `is_valid` line; if we use run or debug with no breakpoint, the client gets a 500 error. This obviously makes it difficult to track down the issue! The view code is below; any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Randal

```
@login_required
def child_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.is_ajax():
            parent_id = request.POST['parent_id']
            parent_instance = get_object_or_404(ParentModel, parent_id=parent_id)
            child_formset = ChildInlineFormSet(request.POST, instance=parent_instance)
            print 'before'
            if child_formset.is_valid():
                print 'after' # never gets here unless breakpoint on previous line
                child_formset.save()
                response = json.dumps({'success': 'true'})
                return HttpResponse(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is because you are only returning an HttpResponse if the `is_valid` check passes, which is why you get a 500 error in other cases.

Your view should look more like:

```
@login_required
def child_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.is_ajax():
            parent_id = request.POST['parent_id']
            parent_instance = get_object_or_404(ParentModel, parent_id=parent_id)
            child_formset = ChildInlineFormSet(request.POST, instance=parent_instance)
            print 'before'
            if child_formset.is_valid():
                print 'after' # never gets here unless breakpoint on previous line
                child_formset.save()
                response = json.dumps({'success': 'true'}) # why string not bool?
                return HttpResponse(response)
            else:
                response = json.dumps({'success': 'false'})
                return HttpResponse(response)
    return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The code does have a response for the error case, but I did not include it because it is not relevant. The problem is the different behaviour in is_valid in debug with breakpoint (runs fine) versus a regular run (dies with an exception somewhere within the is_valid code without returning up to the view function).

Comment: Managed to track it down by putting a breakpoint in django.core.handlers.base.py where it processes Exceptions. Turns out that the the model has a non-required Foreign Key for which we set blank=True but forgot to set null=True. Still doesn't explain why it worked in debug with a breakpoint!

Comment: maybe your breakpoint allows this code to return `True` by avoiding the exception https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.7.3/django/forms/forms.py#L151

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is caused by your debugging evaluating `Form.errors` to display the value of it in the locals window, but `errors` is actually a `@property` method which ends up invoking clean() and the form validation. This is why the behaviour is different when you're hitting the breakpoint. (It's kind of a design flaw in Django IMHO.)

For more information, see this question:
[Debugging form validation in Pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142819/debugging-form-validation-in-pycharm)